# check radio button missed value

Tags: android

i have an issue, to memorize values of EditText and RadioButtons i add @onResume and @onPause methods, it works fine for Edit Text but the problem is that the radio buttons appear checked but when i click to register the value into database, i have message (No value detected), what should i do to resolve the issue ? is there a solution !!!

```
       @Override
protected void onPause() 
{
  super.onPause();
   SharedPreferences prefs3 = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);                                                                                                                  
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs3.edit(); 

  editor.putBoolean("questionA", rm_13_1.isChecked()); 
  editor.putBoolean("questionB", rm_13_2.isChecked());

  editor.putBoolean("questionC", rm_14_1.isChecked());
  editor.putBoolean("questionD", rm_14_2.isChecked());
  editor.putBoolean("questionE", rm_14_3.isChecked());
   // Commit the edits!
  editor.commit();
}

       @Override
    protected void onResume(){
       super.onResume();
       SharedPreferences prefs3 = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
           rm_13_1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rm_13_1)  ;
       rm_13_2  = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rm_13_2);

       rm_14_1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rm_14_1)  ;
       rm_14_2  = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rm_14_2);
           rm_14_3  = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rm_14_2);


            Boolean  rm_13_1A = false;
            Boolean  rm_13_2A = false;

            Boolean rm_14_1A = false;
        Boolean rm_14_2A = false;
        Boolean  rm_14_3A = false;


        rm_13_1A = prefs3.getBoolean("questionA",false);
        rm_13_2A = prefs3.getBoolean("questionB",false);

        rm_14_1A = prefs3.getBoolean("questionC",false);
        rm_14_2A = prefs3.getBoolean("questionD",false);
        rm_14_3A = prefs3.getBoolean("questionE",false); 


       rm_13_1.setChecked(rm_13_1A );
       rm_13_2.setChecked(rm_13_2A );

       rm_14_1.setChecked(rm_14_1A );
       rm_14_2.setChecked(rm_14_2A );
       rm_14_3.setChecked(rm_14_3A );

     }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pref=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreference(this)
```

try

Comment: thanks for responding, where should i write this, i shoudn't delete other pref ?!!

Comment: change your pref for this